# Exclude DIV from initial viewport in mobile browser

Tags: android, html, ios, css

I have to add a div (with some banners) to the right of my actual content. The div is absolute positioned. On a regular laptop/desktop with enough display real estate this is not an issue.

However on a portable device the div is considered part of the content. So the viewport is zoomed to included it. While it is important that the div is included in the output I would prefer it not to be included in the initial view. The actual content should be maximised and I'd would like people to simply be able to side-scroll to the banners - if they choose to (it's not because I'm forced to add banners that I have to prominently position them!).

Is this possible?

Current CSS is as follows:

```
#side-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    right: -140px;
    width: 128px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I'm talking mainly about iOS (both Safari/Chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view you could absolutely accomplish the desired behavior with your CSS code. Maybe the meta element `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` is missing in your page.

Here is an example that worked fine for me on an iPhone 4S with iOS 8.0.2 and a Nexus 5 with Android 4.4.4, at least on the initial page load. When you zoom in or out and just hit the browser refresh button it will stay in the zoomed viewport. But when you load the page again (enter the URL and go) it will be back to the desired behavior.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>banner</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <style>
    #side-container {
      position: absolute;
      top: 90px;
      right: -140px;
      width: 128px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>


</head>

<body>

  <h1>main content</h1>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid atque consectetur consequuntur cum dolorum earum illo itaque laborum, magni, maiores nesciunt nisi provident quasi suscipit tempora ullam velit veritatis voluptatem!
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid atque consectetur consequuntur cum dolorum earum illo itaque laborum, magni, maiores nesciunt nisi provident quasi suscipit tempora ullam velit veritatis voluptatem!
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid atque consectetur consequuntur cum dolorum earum illo itaque laborum, magni, maiores nesciunt nisi provident quasi suscipit tempora ullam velit veritatis voluptatem!
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid atque consectetur consequuntur cum dolorum earum illo itaque laborum, magni, maiores nesciunt nisi provident quasi suscipit tempora ullam velit veritatis voluptatem!
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid atque consectetur consequuntur cum dolorum earum illo itaque laborum, magni, maiores nesciunt nisi provident quasi suscipit tempora ullam velit veritatis voluptatem!
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid atque consectetur consequuntur cum dolorum earum illo itaque laborum, magni, maiores nesciunt nisi provident quasi suscipit tempora ullam velit veritatis voluptatem!
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid atque consectetur consequuntur cum dolorum earum illo itaque laborum, magni, maiores nesciunt nisi provident quasi suscipit tempora ullam velit veritatis voluptatem!
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid atque consectetur consequuntur cum dolorum earum illo itaque laborum, magni, maiores nesciunt nisi provident quasi suscipit tempora ullam velit veritatis voluptatem!
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid atque consectetur consequuntur cum dolorum earum illo itaque laborum, magni, maiores nesciunt nisi provident quasi suscipit tempora ullam velit veritatis voluptatem!
  </p>

  <div id="side-container">
    <h2>banner content</h2>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse nisi, quam. Dolorem doloremque ex pariatur quod rem repudiandae tenetur voluptate. Expedita, harum nesciunt numquam provident quas repellat? Aliquid dolores, maxime?</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```